# Galilean invariance of Burgers Equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

I think the following statement is true: if $u$ solves the burgers equation (ie $u$ solves $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$$ then so does $$u^c = u(x-ct,t)+c.$$ I'm having trouble showing this though.

---

Just an edit to this problem:

This is a simplification of Proposition 1.1, Section 1.2 of Majda and Bertozzi, where I took $\mathbf{c} = \langle c,0,0 \rangle$

The statement is given without proof. When I try to work this out -- I'm not sure where the factor of $c$ is coming from in the $u^c u^c_x$ term. I guess this is trivial?

Comment: This question is about **Galilean relativity** of Burgers equation, used as an example in introduction to elliptic equations in studying compressible flows. It seems to me that it could be a suitable question

Comment: How do you think that, i.e. "the following statement is true"? Galilean relativity involve the transformations of time and space coordinates as perceived by two observers in relative motion at uniform velocity. I don't see here any of these considerations. Have a try and think how space coordinates and velocity measurements transform for two observers in relative motion with uniform velocity $v_r$

Comment: @basic, indeed the statement is true per direct inspection.

Comment: @ValterMoretti yeah! You're right. Galilean transformation is included in the definition of the solution $u^c(x,t)$. This can be interpreted as the solution seen by an observer in motion with velocity $c$ w.r.t. the first observer who sees the solution of the Burgers equation to be $u(x,t)$

Comment: To be more explicit, the solution $u^c(x,t) = u(x-ct,t) + c$ is the relative velocity field w.r.t. an observer moving with velocity $-c$ along the $x$-axis, whose $x'$ coordinate can be related to $x$ by $x' = x-ct$

Comment: @basics I am unclear on which is the correct equation to consider when we move to an observer in a moving reference frame: $u^c(x',t')_{t'}+u^c(x',t') u^c(x',t')_{x'} = 0$ or $u^c(x',t')_t+u^c(x',t') u^c(x',t')_x = 0$. The former seems true because when we move to a new reference frame, we consider burgers equation in new coordinates. However the latter seems to follow from what we mean by invariance of something (e.g. $f(x)$ solves $df(x)/dx = 0$ then so does $f^c(x) = f(x) + c$ -- here we just evaluate $df^c(x)/dx = 0$)

Comment: i cant't upload an answer until the question is closed

Comment: the question appears to be closed to me, it does not to you?: https://snipboard.io/s5C0im.jpg

Comment: I posted this question here as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4566187/galilean-invariance-of-burgers-equation?noredirect=1#comment9607631_4566187